# how to make expandable layout expands in upward direction instead of default behaviour i.e expands downward?

Tags: java, android, expandable

i am new to android and i have an issue that my expandable layout is expanding in downward direction , i want to expand it upward direction as i have the layout in bottom , please help me

```
<net.cachapa.expandablelayout.ExpandableLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandable_layout_0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:el_duration="1000"
    app:el_expanded="false"
    app:el_parallax="0.5">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      android:background="@color/teal_700"/>

</net.cachapa.expandablelayout.ExpandableLayout>
```

Comment: Since you are using 3rd party SDK for expansion. You have to check with the ExpadableLayout library whether they support it or not.
https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout

Comment: another way of achieving this goal???